# Slide In View Animation

Tags: android

I want a relative layout to slide into a screen.

At the moment I set the layout to be below a layout that takes up the whole screen

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ghostIv"
                android:src="@drawable/results_ghost"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ghostShadowIv"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:src="@drawable/results_ghost_shadow"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ghostIv"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/noFilterTv"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/LightTextGrey"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:text="@string/no_filters"
                android:paddingLeft="50dp"
                android:paddingRight="50dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ghostShadowIv"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

        <com.allryder.android.ui.views.ScheduleView
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:background="@color/White"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/scheduleView"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

        <View
                android:id="@+id/shadowV"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_above="@+id/ratingRl"
                android:layout_height="4dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/bottom_shadow"/>

        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/ratingRl"
                android:layout_below="@+id/scheduleView"
                android:background="@color/White"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                    android:background="@drawable/time_view_selector"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:id="@+id/ratePromptTv"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/closeRatingIv"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:gravity="center|left"
                    android:text="@string/rate_prompt"/>
            <ImageView
                    android:background="@drawable/time_view_selector"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ratePromptTv"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ratePromptTv"
                    android:id="@+id/closeRatingIv"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/search_clear"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<fragment android:id="@+id/filters_drawer"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="end"
          android:name="com.allryder.android.ui.fragments.FiltersDrawerFragment"/>
```

Then make this call

```
      ratingRl.animate().translationY(- ratingRl.getHeight());
```

But it doesn't slide into the screen. If the view is in the screen to start off with, the view does animate. What is the problem?

Comment: You want this screen as a slider menu ?

Comment: no I already have a navigation drawer. I want the ratingRl to slide in from the bottom

Answer (score 0):

```
 ratingRl.animate().translationY(- ratingRl.getHeight()).setDuration(300).start();
```

Comment: this is the same as what I am doing but you added a specific duration. So it doesn't work

Comment: Open your eyes. I put a start() at the end. You should do to.

Comment: You don't need start(). As I wrote int he original question if the view is originally visible it DOES animate. But when I change the start postion I run into problems. There is no need to be trolling with you "open your eyes" comment

Comment: Height is 0 maybe? Because it's below the other view it doesn't get layed out? Create it normally on top of the other view, then translate it out of the screen. No trolling intended,

Comment: No, I animate after 1 second so I can get the actual height

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar task in my recent project.

```
background = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.slidingBackground);
positionOffScreen(background);

private void positionOffScreen(View v){
    View myView = v;
    int amountOffscreen = (int)(getScreenWidth());
    boolean offscreen = true;

    int xOffset = (offscreen) ? amountOffscreen : 0;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)myView.getLayoutParams();
    rlParams.setMargins(-1*xOffset, 0, xOffset, 0);
    myView.setLayoutParams(rlParams);
}

protected float getScreenWidth() {
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    return (float) displaymetrics.widthPixels;
}
```

When you want to start animation call this method

```
private void startAnimation(int duration){
    TranslateAnimation a = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE,0,Animation.ABSOLUTE,getScreenWidth(),Animation.ABSOLUTE,0,Animation.ABSOLUTE,0);
    a.setDuration(duration);
    a.setFillAfter(false);
    background.startAnimation(a);
}
```

When you want to interrupt animation

```
background.clearAnimation();
```

Here is layout example. The sliding view has to be placed on `RelativeLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/slidingBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#64000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </RelativeLayout>
    ...
```

And [this](https://play.google.com/store/people/details?id=101467824880100650996) is the app link where I use this sliding view.

Comment: ah it looks like a good solution. I tried something similar but I was trying setY() rather than changing the layoutparams, doh

Comment: I am trying to modify this to slide up from the bottom. But setting the margin doesn't seem to move the view

Comment: @jiduvah I edited my answer. Maybe this will solve your problem.

Comment: Try **Show layout bounds** in android developer options. Maybe this will help you. http://developer.android.com/tools/index.html

Comment: as so this approach does work but I was only setting the top margin and not both the top and bottom so the view was being squashed. Silly mistake but it is not obvious